# Cutting a string Until a particular character occurs

Tags: vb.net, string

whats the code to cut or trim a string until a particular character is hit.

for example,

```
dim TestString as String = "REG - REGULAR"
```

output of this string after cutting should be,

```
"REG"
```

The code should be able to cut the string until it reaches this character "-".

It should also remove the white spaces.
whats the code for doing this task.

I am using vb.net.

Thank You

Comment: can you explain the logic? and what have you tried?

Comment: I had used String.SubString(0,3)
But i want all the char's until this character ("-") and all the white spaces must be removed.

Comment: @Upendra Thank you, I got it. Thats what i wanted exactly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

```
TestString = TestString.Substring(0,TestString.IndexOf('-')).Trim()
```

Comment: The above code works fine if its for the example above,
i.e "REG - REGULAR"

i had used the same code which you have used. 
but it works only for the first 3 char's.
But i want the all the characters, until "-".
for Ex:

Comment: Modified to search '-' character

Comment: The above code works fine if its for the example above,
i.e "REG - REGULAR"

i had used the same code which you have used. 
but it works only for the first 3 char's.
But i want the all the characters, until "-".
for Ex:
"BOI - Bank Of India", After cutting , it should be "BOI".
"HDFC - HDFC Bank", After cutting , it should be "HDFC".
"AB - Allahabad Bank",After cutting , it should be "AB".

Comment: It should work as i have included to search for '-' character, IndexOf function does that.

Comment: Thanks you,it is able to cut string until "-".
but how can i eliminate white spaces until "-".